# Database structure suggestion (serialization or separate table)

Tags: mysql, database, serialization

I am currently making a database, and truth to be told I'm not exactly very good at it (kinda being forced to do it). Its a game database, and I have a table called game_table that I use for storing game sessions that users create.

The question is, what is the best way to store a list of invited users, requested users, confirmed users, declined users and pending users? Currently I am serializing the user IDs (e.g. invited users = "11235|2510|34630|45715|64530"). However, the main problem is that the field becomes not searchable, and it becomes a problem if I want to retrieve a list of games that a user is invited to. To solve that problem, I store a separate field in the user_table for invited_games (also serialized game IDs).

The problem with that, is that it is getting hard to maintain whenever I want to add new features, and it is too easy to make mistakes with keeping the serialized data in sync. Is it better to have separate tables like:

invited_users_table

```
Game_ID  |  User_ID
 51      |   5193
 51      |   10458
 51      |   235
 901     |   1536
 901     |   4573
```

Or is there some other better way of storing these types of data? Please help, and thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's better to have separate tables.  Any time you have a string of delimited values in a single field you *probably* have a broken table design.  For exactly the reasons you specify (and more), you want to keep data elements separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you say, it sounds like you need one table with three columns:

- GameId
- UserId
- UserType

The latter would take on values such as "invited", "confirmed", "requested" and so on.

You would want separate tables if you had more information about the different groups.  For instance, you might have a "who invited" column for invited users, or a "confirmation time" for confirmed users.  If the number of specific columns needed for the different groups is large-ish, then you might want to think about a more complex data structure.  If there are just a handful of such columns, you can add them into the table described above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is better to have a separate table for invited users.

Yet better would be to have `game_user_relation` table, which will store the game id, the user id and the relationship between them. Kinda:

```
create table game_user_relation(
    game_id int not null,
    user_id int not null,
    relation_type varchar (10) not null,
    primary key(game_id, user_id, relation_type)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

This table will allow one user to have many relations to one game.
Or, if you need to have exactly one user relate to one game - remove `relation_type` from primary key.

This way you could select all needed data from one table.